# Order of $\{x\in\mathbb {Z}, |x|+|3x-1|<5\}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, absolute-value

There is a multiple choices which says what is the order of $\{x\in\mathbb {Z}, |x|+|3x-1|<5\}$?

a. 1

b. 3

c. 2

d. empty

I know that by considering certain cases, for example when $x<0$ or $x\le 1/3$, we can find the answer which is $2$. I am just curious if there is a faster way than mine to find the solutions? Indeed, it is a multile choices and so we haven't enough time. Thank you!

Comment: A look shows the solutions are $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Comment: I wish I could have your looking. :) Indeed, I am scared treating these kinds of problem as you did. I just think of handy calculations. And that's why I asked it here. :)

Comment: Since $3$ is close to $5$, the inequality $|3x-1|<5$ is bound to have very few solutions all close to $\frac{1}{3}$, and then $|x|+|3x-1|<5$ even fewer. Check $1$, good, check $2$, bad, check $0$, good, check $-1$, bad, done - all this can be done mentally, quickly. Even the answer choices suggest that you barely have to do any checking. *If* they instead suggested a lot more potential solutions, then indeed you'd need a better method than checking.

Comment: It seems that your way could make it solved. Thanks whacka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle it case by case:
$$
x\ge0\text{ and }x\ge\frac13\text{ and }4x-1\lt5\implies x\in\left[\frac13,\frac32\right)
$$
$$
x\ge0\text{ and }x\lt\frac13\text{ and }1-2x\lt5\implies x\in\left[0,\frac13\right)
$$
$$
x\lt0\text{ and }x\ge\frac13\text{ and }2x-1\lt5\implies x\in\varnothing
$$
$$
x\lt0\text{ and }x\lt\frac13\text{ and }1-4x\lt5\implies x\in\left(-1,0\right)
$$
Put it together:
$$
x\in\left(-1,\frac32\right)\implies x\in\{0,1\}
$$

Comment: Oops... they know this. I was just about to delete this. However, you accepted it. Does that mean you find it useful?

Comment: Thank you robjohn. Yes it helps. :)

Comment: @neda_HD: because of a fluke when I deleted/undeleted my answer, your acceptance was also deleted. Would you mind unaccepting and reaccepting this answer?